# Don't call to method useEffect() when I call to axios.get function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, fetch

I have a view in react that it has two useEffect one to order a list, and other to get the list.
"isLoading" allows to see all list when dataTailors has values.

```
export const  ClientMainPage = () => {
  const [dataTailors, setDataTailors] = useState([]);
  const [sortItemSelected, setSortItemSelected] = useState("none");  
  const [isfetch, setIsfetch] = useState(false);  

  useEffect( () => {
    setIsfetch(true);
    let uFetchAux = new uFetch();
    uFetchAux.getAllTailors().then (res => setDataTailors(res));
    console.log(dataTailors);
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sortByNameItems = (itemSeleted) => {
      const options = {
        asc: [...dataTailors].sort((a, b) => (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1)),
        desc: [...dataTailors].sort((a, b) => (a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1)),
        none: [...dataTailors]
      };
      return options[itemSeleted];
    };
    setDataTailors(sortByNameItems(sortItemSelected));
  }, [sortItemSelected]);


  return (
      <div className="MainPage">
        {isfetch?(   <div>
        <NavBar title="Cliente">
          <SortBy sortItems={(items) => setSortItemSelected(items)}></SortBy>
        </NavBar>        
        <ClientTable tailors={dataTailors}></ClientTable></div>)
        :<div>{setIsfetch(false)}</div>
        }
      </div>
      
    
  );
};
```

This is muy interface to call to my service, which it is up in the "http://localhost:8088".

```
import axios from "axios";

class  uFetch  {
    async getAllTailors() {
        const http = axios.create({
            baseURL: "http://localhost:8088",
            headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
            },
            responseType: "json",
            mode: "cors",
        });
        return await http.get("/tailor")
        .then( resp => {console.log(resp.data); return resp.data })
        .catch(e => {console.log(e); });;     
    }
}
export default uFetch;
```

When I execute this code. The useEffects don't execute

The useEffects execute, and get the list

Comment: Have you tried adding logs to both useEffect functions? What behaviour are you experiencing? Is only one of the loops not executing? Also, calling a state setter during render feels like a massive code smell

Comment: Your first `useEffect()` will only run its callback if the value of `sortItems` is modified with a call to `setSortItems()`.  So is that happening?  Is `sortItems` being given a different value?  We can't see what `<SortBy>` is doing; how is it using the value of its `sortItems` prop?  (BTW: overloading the name `sortItems` is not a good idea...in our code it is used for 3 entirely separate things...consider renaming 2 of them)

Comment: Well @WilhelmErasmus, I put "console.log"; but it is undefinied because it passes through the useEffects. If I call it outside the useEffects. first is pending and when all render get the list, but anything loading

Comment: @GregFenton, in my oode any useEffect is executed.  Thanks I will change the name of the sortItem to fix overloading

Comment: Suggestion: when you use `console.log()` put some *unique* prefix to each message so that you know where a particular console message is coming from in your code.  Something like `console.log("useEffect #2: dataTailors", dataTailors);`

Comment: If the useEffect's callback is not being called, then that means the conditions of the callback are not being met.  For your first `useEffect()`, it will run whenever `sortItems` has a new value.  For your second, it will only run the very first render of the component and then it will not run again.

Comment: @GregFenton. Anything. It didn't work

Comment: Please define "didn't work".  Also, please update the code in your post showing what you are now running.  That way we're all "on the same page".

Comment: You better migrate this project to start using react-query or redux-toolkit-query, they'll save you years of headache

Comment: It's not easy to answer this question without seeing the console logs, can you make a simple reproducible code in code-sandbox?

Comment: Your line `console.log(dataTailors);` in the first useEffect will not show the newly downloaded data.  It will only show the initial value of `[ ]`.  Put a `console.log("about to return JSX:", dataTailors);` on the line just before your component's `return()` to see what the value is just as the component is outputting its UI.  The thing to realize is that the "set state function" is asynchronous (not `async`...it doesn't return a Promise), so you will not be able to access the "new values" of the state variable until the next time the component renders.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
 export const  ClientMainPage = () => {
  const [dataTailors, setDataTailors] = useState([]);
  const [sortItemSelected, setSortItemSelected] = useState("none");  

  useEffect( () => {
    getAllTailors().then(d=> {console.log( "call inside " +d); setDataTailors(d) });
    console.log( "useEffect " +dataTailors);
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sortByNameItems = (itemSeleted) => {
      const options = {
        asc: [...dataTailors].sort((a, b) => (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1)),
        desc: [...dataTailors].sort((a, b) => (a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1)),
        none: [...dataTailors]
      };
      return options[itemSeleted];
    };
    setDataTailors(sortByNameItems(sortItemSelected));
  }, [sortItemSelected]);

  if (!dataTailors) return null;

  return (
      <div className="MainPage">
        <div>
        <NavBar title="Cliente">
          <SortBy sortItems={(items) => setSortItemSelected(items)}></SortBy>
        </NavBar>        
        <ClientTable tailors={dataTailors}></ClientTable></div>
      </div>
      
    
  );
};
```

and

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getAllTailors = async () => {
    const http = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8088",
        headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        responseType: "json",
        mode: "cors",
    });
    return await http.get("/tailor")
    .then( (resp) => {console.log("getAllTailors " + resp.data); return   resp.data })
    .catch(e => {console.log(e); });
   }
```